# 'Failed to create a ImageSource from the text '..\Images\Medium.png' failed to Add New Reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

When I try to Add a New Reference to my current Project it gives me this error 'Failed to create a ImageSource from the text '..\Images\Medium.png'

I searched on goggle and here but most answers where to uninstall the FastPictureViewer Codec Pack 2.4 which I do not have installed.

The other recommendation was to change the permission of "modify" for "everybody" on the files

c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config

and

c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config

but I can't find this "modify" so I can change to "everybody", can someone help?

Comment: You are trying to include a picture in your project, am I right in assuming that? To later use elsewhere in your code. Also, are you using WPF or WinForm?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you do Project Menu ->Refresh Toolbox items in Visual Studio? I STRONGLY suspect one of your toolbox items is unable to create its icon because the config for one of the control in your toolbox is wrong.

Comment: I have the same situation.. Tried almost every "solution" I could found but no luck... Please add here if you can find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Go to windows update of your PC and install all the optional an recommended updates.

Restart your pc and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Due to Upgrade Window 8 To Windows 8.1 you will get issues.
I have the same but Resolved with this solution.
 Go to Control Panel
Click on Window Update
After Update Restart System
You will find problem Resolved.