# Microchip Studio/Visual Studio2015 (AVR Studio) failed to create new project

Tags: visual-studio, avr-studio7

When I try to create a new project (FILE -> New -> Project or from welcome page) it pops up with an error message dialogbox saying "Failed to create a ImageSource from the text '..\Images\Medium.png'.

Where the file is located???

I have an old installation of VS2015 and 2019 on Windows 10

I try many things:

- In Sandbox all runs well
- I delete all I can from Windows Settings like VS 2015, 2019, .NET 4.x and so on
- I install 2015 and 2019 new and deinstall it again

In advanced: saying "install Windows new" is no help

I try many things:

- In Sandbox all runs well
- I delete all I can from Windows Settings like VS 2015, 2019, .NET 4.x and so on
- I install 2015 and 2019 new and deinstall it again

Comment: Duplicates: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493701/failed-to-create-imagesource-from-the-text-images-medium-png), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380986/failed-to-create-a-imagesource-from-the-text-images-medium-png-failed-to-a), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257817/visual-studio-2012-failed-to-create-project)

Comment: Nothing helps. Win 8.1 problems!